# Does the iphone have a built in dictionary that other apps can access?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

In one of my application i need to check that spelling of word is correct or not.
so I what's to know, Does the iphone have a built in dictionary that other apps can access?
if yes, then how to do that.

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone SDK does not provide programmatic access to any spelling dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a UITextField or UITextView that the user is typing into, you can enable "correction" which will auto suggest/correct any spelling mistakes the user types. Just like when typing an email or sending an sms. This behaviour is inherent in all text entry classes in UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

The Second Edition of the Oxford English Dictionary contains full entries for 171,476 words in current use

The average length of English words is 4.5 letters

In bytes that would be 4.5 per word

Therefore 171,476 x 4.5 = 771,642 bytes to store all the words

In MB that would be **0.735895157**

So what I'm trying to say is, you ***have*** enough storage to have your own dictionary :)

Comment: thanx for reply Keith, but i don't know how to use that dictionary. If u have any link or documentation please give it to me

Comment: Just google it - there are loads of dictionary files available. If you have a linux box then go to /usr/share/dict/words